# Postfix / Spamassassin: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender

Tags: configuration, email, postfix-mta, spamassassin

I'm having an issue with a newly configured mailserver where spam emails that are spoofed to come from the local domain are actually accepted by the mailserver, the mail isnt delivered as is though, the spamassassin tags it as spam and then send an email "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" to the spoofed local user.

I know there is a way of fixing this in the configuration but i have no idea where, i'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

To be clear, the mailserver is not relaying, this is only a local user issue.
I want postfix to reject any emails supposedly from local users that aren't sent internally. It would stop this problem.

Here is an email to show you whats happening. I've changed the domain to example.com.au.

> ###############################################
>
> This is the mail system at host example.com.au. 
>   
>   I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not 
>   be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>   
>   For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>   
>   If you do so, please include this problem report. You can 
>   delete your own text from the attached returned message.
>   
>   The mail system
>   
>   : host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 554 5.7.0 Reject, id=11887-07 - SPAM (in reply to end of DATA command) 
>  ? 
>   Reporting-MTA:dns; example.com.au
>   X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 661DC5D1DE
>   X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; dan@example.com.au
>   Arrival-Date: Tue, 5 May 2009 06:21:38 +1000 (EST)
>   
>   Final-Recipient: rfc822;dan@example.com.au 
>   Original-Recipient:rfc822;dan@example.com.au
>   Action: failed Status: 5.7.0 
>   Remote-MTA: dns; 127.0.0.1 
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.0 Reject, id=11887-07 - SPAM ?
>   
>   **From: Berenice Penez** 
>   Date: Mon, 4
>   May 2009 22:21:41 +0200
>   **To:**  Subject: Were it you, on forum?
>   
>   Reliable quality and no delays with
>   delivery! Super online store for
>   disease treating
>   http://www.xopfekec.cn/
>
> ###############################################

Postfix main.cf (the important parts, not complete)

> readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
>   mydomain_fallback = localhost
>   message_size_limit = 0
>   mailbox_size_limit = 0
>   myhostname = example.com.au
>   mailbox_transport = cyrus
>   mydomain = example.com.au
>   inet_interfaces = all
>   enable_server_options = yes
>   mydestination = $myhostname,localhost.$mydomain,localhost,example.com.au
>   smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
>   smtpd_use_pw_server = yes
>   smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_invalid_hostname
>   smtpd_pw_server_security_options = plain,login
>   content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
>   mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.1.0/24
>   smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net

Comment: Sorry man, should be on serverfault.com

Comment: Plus that looks like every third email in my Gmail's spam folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few different points:

- This should be on serverfault.com, but since I'm not on the beta there I'll answer it here.
- The output of *postconf -n* is better than including what you think are the relevant lines in main.cf. Also include relevant lines from master.cf if you have parameter overrides or other customisations in there.
- Don't accept then bounce mail like that. If you are using SpamAssassin as an after-queue filter in Postfix (the usual way of running it), you need to either tag-and-deliver (and filter with client-side rules) or quarantine the mail without notifying the sender. From the look of your question, you are probably a backscatter source. Stop it. See for example http://www.postfix.org/BACKSCATTER_README.html. Do consider amavisd-new for integrating SpamAssassin into Postfix with all kinds of useful features.
- Consider collapsing all of your restrictions into smtpd_recipient_restrictions. It's generally easier to manage the linear flow of restrictions like that than to deal with the interactions between smtpd_{client,helo,sender,recipient}_restrictions.
- To prevent Postfix from accepting mail from outside, add a sender_access map that rejects mail claiming to be from your domains:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
  permit_sasl_authenticated, 
  permit_mynetworks, 
  reject_unauth_destination, 
  check_sender_access hash:$config_directory/reject_mydomains
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain,
  reject_invalid_hostname
```

And in reject_mydomains

```
example.com.au REJECT you are not me
```

This will probably be prone to false positives with mail that comes from senders with a legitimate(?) reason to use your domain as the envelope sender (E-cards, invitations, maybe some outsourced service like surveys or whatnot). You can whitelist around your you-are-not-me rules with a client_access map before your sender_access map that returns OK or an appropriate restriction class (see http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html).

You can use similar HELO checks to weed out clients HELO-ing with your own Hostname/IP or known bad HELO strings

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
  permit_sasl_authenticated, 
  permit_mynetworks, 
  reject_unauth_destination, 
  check_helo_access hash:$config_directory/helo_checks
  check_sender_access hash:$config_directory/reject_mydomains
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain,
  reject_invalid_hostname
```

and in helo_checks:

```
example.com.au             REJECT BAD-HELO you are not example.com.au
mailserver.example.com.au  REJECT BAD-HELO you are not me
localhost                  REJECT BAD-HELO you are not me
localhost.localdomain      REJECT BAD-HELO you are not me
# where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of your server
1.2.3.4                    REJECT BAD-HELO you are not me
127.0.0.1                  REJECT BAD-HELO you are not me
```

Lastly, it's a very good idea to subscribe to a good reputation service such as an RBL. The best RBL for most purposes is [zen.spamhaus.org](http://www.spamhaus.org/ZEN/). It's free to use for light to moderate loads, and if your usage is high enough to cross over their free/paid threshold, the cost is well worth it. To configure in Postfix, add

```
reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
```

to your smtpd_recipient_restrictions. Do that after your cheap local checks to save on DNS query load and latency, but before expensive local checks like reject_unverified_recipient (you aren't using that one and probably don't need it from your problem description).

Comment: Wow, so much helpful information. I haven't had a chance to test anything but the helo_checks sound like exactly what i need.

Also, this is OSX Server 10.5.6, which barely works out of the box. 
I've configured it to forward all spam to spam@example.com.au, there shouldn't be any backscatter, and if there is then i'm blaming it on apples terrible configuration. I'll check and make sure its not sending backscatter.

Thanks again, and also i had no idea serverfault.com existed...

Comment: Glad to help (please upvote or accept the answer if it helps).

Note that the check_sender_access is the important part for your specific question. The HELO checks are nice to have and an easy way to weed out particular kinds of bad clients.

One thing I missed in my original answer was to subscribe to a good RBL. Zen.spamhaus.org is the best default choice. I'll edit the answer to incluse that.

Comment: I've tried some of these to no avail. I wrote a quick php script to test it and the mailserver still happily receives externally sent mail from: daniel@example.com.au rcpt to: daniel@example.com.au<br><br> I'm also fairly sure its not sending backscatter but i have no idea how to test it thoroughly.

Comment: Ok, after screwing with the server a whole lot more i've learned a few things. The first thing i learned is that i hate postfix. The second thing is that, the server im using is actually sending backscatter. So i'd love to know how to get spamassassin to discard emails it identifies as spam rather than bouncing them. it would probably fix all my problems.